# How to return the value to the global variable to be used?

Tags: random, arduino, global-variables, lcd

I'm facing a problem. I need to use the random number generated in the void loop from `randomseed()` to be displayed on the LCD and also being stored in an array. I simply can't display the random number in the LCD. All I get is a blank LCD screen. I'll comment in the code below:

```
int randNumber; 
long randNumber1; 
const int led_pin = 13; 
const int transmit_pin = 12; 
const int receive_pin = 2;  
const int transmit_en_pin = 3;  
LiquidCrystal lcd(9, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin80, INPUT);
  pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
  SetupRFDataTxnLink(transmit_pin, baudRate);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  // generate a random no. if there is no analog input 
}
void loop() {
  float outArray[RF_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE];
  //the number of elements that
  randNumber = random(0, 255);
  //here is where the randNumber are generated.
  randNumber1 = random(90,150);
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin80);
  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState1 == HIGH) {
    // if the button is pressed, send the generated no. to the transmitter.
    outArray[0] = randNumber;
    // Here is where the randNumber generated from the void loop
    outArray[1] = randNumber1;
    outArray[2] = 80;
    outArray[3] = 0;
    union RFData outDataSeq;
    EncodeRFData(outArray, outDataSeq);
    TransmitRFData(outDataSeq);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(randNumber);
    // Here is where I need the randomNumber for
```

My question is can I constantly generate a randNumber that is store in a global variable to be used anywhere in this sketch?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why so many types ? you use `long` `int` `float`  for your random number
Have you tried to print a basic `helloworld` ?

Comment: @Ôrel i've tried, the normal string works when the line of code are in the setup(), but it just simply don't run in the void loop(), and the randNumber wont even printed out when this code are inserted "lcd.print(randNumber)"

Comment: How did you wire your button? I'm pretty sure that you didn't put any pullup or pulldown and connected the button with one pin to ground and the other to buttonPin80 (BTW, you didn't write it in the code..). If I'm right,  write `pinMode(buttonPin80, INPUT);` instead that `INPUT` and `buttonState1 = !digitalRead(buttonPin80);` (since the button is active low, you have to invert the buttonstate logic).